# How can I search strings inside an array using wild cards? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search, wildcard

The parameter is a string that has a number in each word. I need to search that word for the number. My solution so far is to split the string up into a string array, and use `Array.IndexOf` to find the matching index of my search. However I haven't been able to find a way to successfully use wildcards. Using `string.Contains` seems to work, but searching with `Array.IndexOf` doesn't.

How can I search a string array element for a word that contains a number and return it's index? 1-9.

```cs
public static string Order(string words)
        {
            string[] wordArr = words.Split(' ');
            string[] wordsOrdered = new string[words.Length];
            int k;
            for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < wordsOrdered.Length; i++, j++)
            {
                if (words.Contains($"{j}"))
                {
                    k = Array.IndexOf(wordArr, $"{j}");
                    if (k != -1)
                        wordsOrdered[i] = wordArr[k];
                }
            }
            return words = wordsOrdered.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your inputs and the expected output?

Comment: example input: "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"
example output: "Thi1s is2 3a T4est"

I know this doesn't seem very useful, it's really just for learning on my part.

Comment: Take a look at `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Regular Expression that looks for the presence of digits in your words seems the most simple solution

```
public static string Order(string words)
{
    string[] wordArr = words.Split(' ');
    string[] wordsOrdered = new string[wordArr.Length];

    Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");
    for (int i = 0; i < wordArr.Length; i++)
    {
        var m = r.Match(wordArr[i]);
        if(m.Success)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
            wordsOrdered[index-1] = wordArr[i];
        }
    }
    return string.Join(" ", wordsOrdered);
}
```

This code assumes that all your words have at least one number internally and the lowest number start at 1. (A 0 will result in an index out of range exception) and also you shouldn't have numbers that are greater than then count of the input words.

Comment: `var result = Regex.Matches(words, @"\w*\d\w*").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`